# two Admin notices are coming

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get a notice to admin if any user changes his/her current profile values. the code works but the issue is two emails are coming once information is updated. how I can get this issue resolved?

my code is

```
function my_update() {
    

global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $message = '<h3>the user : <span style="color:blue">' .$current_user->display_name . " </span>has updated profile</h3> submitted values:\n<hr>";
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );  
            $message .= substr($key, 0, -3) . " : ". $value ."<br>";
        }

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );      
@wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), 'User Profile Update', $message);
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

}

function set_html_content_type() {

    return 'text/html';
}
add_action('profile_update','my_update');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got this resolved by adding

```
function my_update() {
if(did_action('profile_update') === 1) {
/*my code here*/
}   
}
```

got some time to find the solution.i found the solution from [here](https://pippinsplugins.com/detect-when-an-action-has-run-with-did_action/)